# Creating arrays and using the data in a label in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton, ibaction

I had an app about a decade ago that I have not updated. I recently found the code and am attempting to bring it into Xcode with Swift. I have my storyboard in good shape, and the beginnings of a workable code, though I cannot successfully translate my old approach into the new language.

The app will have numbered UIButtons that need to populate an Array. Labels will collect the Array items in the order in which they are entered by the user as an IBAction. Label one (Aa) will need to include Array item at index 0, Label two (Ab) at index 1, etc.

I am having trouble, so far as I can tell, having the Label name enter the array and pulling that information out. I know its a simple problem, but it has been 7 years since I have coded and want to get my app going again!

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var rowAsEntered: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Aa: UILabel!

  var primeRow = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    clearAll()    }

func clearAll()
{
    rowAsEntered.text = ""
    primeRow.removeAll()
    Aa.text = ""
    Ab.text = ""
    Ac.text = ""
    Ad.text = ""
    Ae.text = ""
    Af.text = ""
    Ag.text = ""
    Ah.text = ""
    Ai.text = ""
    Aj.text = ""
    Ak.text = ""
    Al.text = ""

 
}
@IBAction func backTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if(!row.isEmpty)
    
    {
        primeRow.removeLast()
    }
}

@IBAction func clearTap(_ sender: Any) {
    clearAll() }


func addToPrimeRow(value: Array<Int>){
    
    Aa.text = primeRow [0]
    Ab.text = primeRow [1]
    Ac.text = primeRow [2]
    Ad.text = primeRow [3]
    Ae.text = primeRow [4]
    Af.text = primeRow [5]
    Ag.text = primeRow [6]
    Ah.text = primeRow [7]
    Ai.text = primeRow [8]
    Aj.text = primeRow [9]
    Ak.text = primeRow [10]
    Al.text = primeRow [11]    
 
}



@IBAction func zeroTap(_ sender: Any){
    addToPrimeRow.append(0)
    
}

@IBAction func oneTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(1)
}

@IBAction func twoTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(2)}

@IBAction func threeTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(3)
}

@IBAction func fourTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(4)
}

@IBAction func fiveTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(5)
}

@IBAction func sixTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(6)
}

@IBAction func sevenTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(7)
}

@IBAction func eightTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(8)
}

@IBAction func nineTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(9)
}

@IBAction func tenTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(10)
}

@IBAction func elevenTap(_ sender: Any) {
    addToPrimeRow.append(11)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend that you use an array of buttons/labels. You can then use a singular `func tapped(_ sender: Any)` with a switch statement inside to process the action according to the index of the button. (Check out vadian's answer to this post here: [Array of UIButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068413/array-of-uibuttons-in-swift-4))
2. `addToPrimeRow.append()` is not going to work for you because `addToPrimeRow` is declared as a function. `append` is for array data structures.
3. You're attempting to assign an Int to `label.text` which requires a string. This is an easy fix, just cast it `String(Int)`.

With the above, it will look something like this:

```html
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!

@IBAction func tappedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let index = boxes.index(of: sender) else { return }
    updateLabel(at: index, to: String(index))
}

// added a second param newText to updateLabel in case you want
// to update the label text to something other than the index
// if you don't want to do that, you can just cast the index
// to a string doing String(index) inside of updateLabel and remove the second param
func updateLabel(at index: Int, to newText: String) {
  guard let updatingLabel = labels[index] else { return }
  updatingLabel.text = newText
}
```

***UPDATE***

Based on additional context from the comments, I've modified some of the code from my original answer.

Desired behavior: tapping on buttons will populate labels with the tapped button value in the order that they've been tapped

```html
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!

@IBAction func tappedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
  guard let index = boxes.index(of: sender) else { return }
  updateNextLabel(withValue: index)
}

func updateNextLabel(withValue value: Int) {
  // find the next label that doesn't have text yet
  let nextLabel = labels.first(where: {$0.text.isEmpty})
  // you need to cast the int value to a string to assign it to the label
  nextLabel.text = String(value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it still isn't quite performing in the manner needed. I simply have 12 buttons that must pass their value into 12 labels in the order in which the user presses them. I will add functionality after that. My label.text wants a string and my strings won't give up individual values without being an array and my arrays give me my values but my labels will not take ints.

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired behavior is when you say "label.text wants a string and my strings won't give up individual values without being an array?". And as explained above in my answer (3), it's expected that label will not take an int. You have to cast the int to a string with `String(Int)`.

Comment: I have mostly solved it with this:

 @IBAction func zeroTap(_ sender: UIButton){
        primeRow.append(0)
        let indexZero = primeRow[0]
        let indexOne = primeRow[1]
        let indexTwo = primeRow[2]
        etc.

        Aa.text = "\(indexZero)"
        Ab.text = "\(indexOne)"
        Ac.text = "\(indexTwo)"
        etc.

The only problem I have left is, of course, "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" unless I have all the array items inserted before called. "If" seems to be the way to go, though I haven't yet coded the solution.

Comment: I haven't yet tried your updated code from the UPDATE. I will put that in later tonight and try it out. Thank you for your suggestions!